# How do I check what type I am dealing with?

Tags: types, haxe

Simply said: I am looking for a Haxe equivalent for Java's `instanceof`.

This is my specific problem:

I have a class `Tile` which contains a field `content` of type `Unit` and a function `get_content()` that returns the currently stored object. `Unit` is an interface which is implemented in 3 classes `Player`, `Monster` and `Item`. Also, i have more specific monsters (like `Dragon` or `Beast`) and I defined each in their own class. Each of them extends the `Monster` class.

Now I want to execute different code depending on what type the object returned by `tile.get_content()` is. For example if it is any object that inherits from the `Monster` class `myFunction1()` is called and if it is anything that extends the `Item` class `myFunction2()` is called.

How would I achieve this behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I found that `if (Type.typeof(tile.get_content()) == Monster)` seems to be the way to go, but does this return true for types that inherit from the `Monster` class aswell or only for objects of the generic class `Monster`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by George, `Std.isOfType()` should be used.

To answer my own second question from the edit: It **does** return `true` for objects of classes which inherit from the specified class.

The full code for my specific example would therefore be

```
if (Std.isOfType(tile.get_content(), Monster)) {
   myFunction1();
} else if (Std.isOfType(tile.get_content(), Item)) {
   myFunction2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there's two:

```
if (tile.get_content() is Monster)
//and
if (Std.isOfType(tile.get_content(), Monster))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why there is two of them, how they differ or whether they return true only for the exact class Monster or also for classes that inherit from it? Just for other users stumbling upon this. I'll look it up/test it now anyway :D

Comment: Also the keyword "is" in the first suggestion seems to not exist.

Comment: And `isOfType` needs a capital "O".

Comment: `is` is available as operator [since haxe 4.2](https://haxe.org/download/version/4.2.0/), are you using latest version ?

Comment: I use Haxe 4.2.3, but it probably did not get recognized because my "Haxe Toolkit Support" plugin in IntelliJ is the old version 1.3.1 for IntelliJ 2020.x. All newer versions had some problems for me. I did not compile the code though, because the syntax highlighting suggested it won't work.